# How to get session attribute with a dynamic key in EL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

If I set session like this:

```
<% 
session.setAttribute("taintedAttribute", "what ever we want");
%>
```

normally we can get session variable like this in EL

```
${sessionScope.taintedAttribute }
```

But how about if I want to do like this

```
<% 
String name = "taintedAttribute";
//session.setAttribute(name, "what ever we want");
session.getAttribute(name);
%>
```

Then how can we call it in EL?

Can EL get something like `${sessionScope.---dynamic name ---}`?

If I do this:

```
<c:set var="name" value="taintedAttribute" />
<c:out value="${sessionScope.[name]}"/>
```

the name will be replaced by `taintedAttribute` as the same as this line

```
${sessionScope.taintedAttribute}
```

Is that possible? How can I do that?

Comment: how about not writing the java code in scriptlets and doing it all server side, maintaining MVC as much as possible.

Comment: i wanted to use only jstl in the jsp pages. That is why i ask how to do this. hehe. i need this code to check on this session, to display something in jsp.

Comment: @NurAini: The point is, you're not supposed to change the application state (this includes session attributes) in JSP at all. Whether it's using scriptlets or JSTL.

Comment: I am sorry. Its not that i wanted to change any of the application state.. I just wanted to check whether that session attribute exist or not.. I have edit the question because i made a mistake. I actually want something like session.getAttribute(name) in jstl.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```html
<c:set var="name" value="taintedAttribute" />
<c:out value="${sessionScope.[name]}"/>
```

You were close. Remove the period.

```html
<c:set var="name" value="taintedAttribute" />
<c:out value="${sessionScope[name]}"/>
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Examples of EL expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html)

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSTL/JSTLSetVariablesScope.htm

```
<c:set var="test" value="Session Level Value"
    scope="session" />
<c:out value="${sessionScope.test}" />
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, i am sorry i made a mistake in the code. I have editted the question and commented the line that is wrong. I actually wanted to write in jstl something like session.getAttribute(name). is that something that can be done in jstl?