# EL is not working in jsp 3.1

Tags: jsp, el

I am using eclipse mars, JDK8, Tomcat 8.

this is my JSP page

```
<%@page import="com.cutm.pogo.User"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>User Page</title>
<link href="css/nodue_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
........
<%  User user = (User)session.getAttribute("LOGIN");
    out.print(user.getName());      %>
${user.name }
```

I have used out.print wich is working for me but not EL.

here is web.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
```

please help to find mistake i have made.

Comment: you should access the LOGIN attribute instead. I can't remember if the EL will search in every scope.

Comment: Thanks for your responce. In the code i Have used ${session.LOGIN.email } this is also not working

Comment: `sessionScope` and not `session` ;) Look at these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309261/how-to-get-session-attribute-with-a-dynamic-key-in-el

Comment: Thanks AxelH I took sometime to understand ${Login.name} working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access a session attribute directly using :

```
 ${sessionScope.LOGIN.name}
```

PS : I recommand you to never put Java code into the JSP since the EL and the JSTL exist. This will be more readable ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it works: you need to make that variable available to access it in EL / JSTL. So using setAttribute, you can set the value.

```
    <%
    User user = (User)session.getAttribute("LOGIN");
    pageContext.setAttribute("userobj", user);
    %>
    ${userobj.name}
```

Comment: Thank you this is working ... why session attribute value is not working. EL should work for every scope as per book

Comment: This is a bad work-around, you should access the session attribute without the need of a java scriplet (never new how to call the java code in a JSP ;) ). Actually, using Java in a JSP is simply a bad design.